# rake db: commands show NoMethodError: undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-5, rake

When rake db: commands are executed, it shows an error

```
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby26, which recognizes
warning: 2.6.7-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.6.2.
warning: please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/rake: No such file or directory - which yarn
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass
C:/.../config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This happens on a Windows10 machine, but the mac machine is working fine without errors. It's a Ruby on rails application.
Here's the environment.rb:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
The output of running rake with the --trace flag to see where exactly the NoMethodError was coming from (`rake --trace db:migrate`):

```
rake --trace db:migrate
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby26, which recognizes
warning: 2.6.7-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.6.2.
warning: please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/rake: No such file or directory - which yarn
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mjml-rails-4.6.1/lib/mjml.rb:68:in `check_for_yarn_mjml_binary'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mjml-rails-4.6.1/lib/mjml.rb:44:in `valid_mjml_binary'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mjml-rails-4.6.1/lib/mjml/railtie.rb:13:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
```

Comment: I see several issues. Line 2: Seems like you are not using the correct Ruby version for your app. Line 4: Seems like you do not have `yarn` installed. Line 6-8: Feels to me like your database config is incorrect or missing.

Comment: Thank you for your response @spickermann Regarding the warnings - these are not an issue when setting up on mac and have not been on Windows earlier, so the current issue shouldn’t be related to that. The yarn has also been successfully installed.
It could be related to the database. Postgres is set up fine and is connected to the right port and localhost. Since db:create didn't work, I set up the databases independently and should be with the right properties (matching database.yml). I am right now trying to test if this somehow is not the case. Any ideas for commands I can run to test this?

Comment: Try running `rake` with the `--trace` flag to see exactly where the `NoMethodError` is coming from. Something like `rake --trace db:migrate`. Also, can you run other `rake` commands like a simple `rake -T`?

Comment: @MikeGorski I've edited the post for some code, please check.
So, it seems like it has something related to ```mjl```.
I'm able to run other rake commands like a simple rake -T.

Comment: From the looks of line 68 in `mjml-rails-4.6.1/lib/mjml.rb` you are going to have problems on Windows with this gem. By default Windows doesn't support the `which` command. Are you using Windows 10 Subsystem for Linux by chance?

Comment: I've answered the question, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

My team and I, on the investigation, found out that the versions specified in the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock were different. The versions had got upgraded explicitly, so we'd had to load a predefined Gemfile.lock, and bringing gems on the same version solved the issue.
So, for anyone else facing this issue, please check the versions (of the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock).

PS. To much of our surprise, it didn't actually have anything to do with the database config.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, when I was running Ruby version 2.7.4 on Windows 11 and a command
rake db:migrate
ERROR:
C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/rake: No such file or directory - which yarn
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass
FIX:
Installed which, using chocolatey on windows 11 from the following link, https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/which
& RUN bundle install
solved the error.